# Can lxml / scrapy selector not transfer the html entities

Tags: python, scrapy, lxml, html-entities, parsel

How to get the original html entities after using the lxml / scrapy selector xpath?

I've already tried lxml instead of the parsel package, same issue.

```py
mytext = '<html><body><span>go&nbsp;od</span></body></html>'
sel = parsel.Selector(text=mytext)
sel.xpath('//body').extract()
```

Actual output:

```
['<body><span>go\xa0od</span></body>']
```

Expected output:

```
['<body><span>go&nbsp;od</span></body>']
```

The `&nbsp;` got converted, how to keep them as it is?

Comment: `<body><span>go od</span></body>` is that what you mean by your desired output?

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, currently, `.extract()` and `.getall()` methods return raw html **with** unicode characters like `\xa0` i.e. `&nbsp;`. More info [here](https://parsel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#extract-and-extract-first).

However, `.extract_first()` and `.get()` method return only the first in the list and the output is **without** unicode characters. ([Docs](https://parsel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parsel.html#parsel.selector.Selector.get))

```py
print(sel.xpath('//body').get())
```

Outputs:

```
<body><span>go od</span></body>
```

---

But if you really wanted to have `&nbsp;` chracters instead of `''` or `\xa0`. Then one solution is to do a regular string replace for those characters.

Example:

```py
body = sel.xpath('//body').extract()

result = [i.replace('\xa0', '&nbsp;') for i in body]

print(result)
```

Outputs:

```
['<body><span>go&nbsp;od</span></body>']
```

Comment: Hi Rithin, thanks for the answer. Since the `&nbsp;` is not the only html entities we want to keep, so I think a method that can directly output the original html entities without any further replace would be better.

Comment: @XiaojinLiu,  any specific reason for not using `<body><span>go od</span></body>`? What's the context of needing the original entities?

Comment: Because we want to save the original html files for recrawl in the future

Comment: @XiaojinLiu, you can try saving it before passing it to selector?

Comment: Hi Rithin, we don't have a plan to save the whole html file, we only interested in part of them. So that's why we need selector help us grab it.